# Firefox stops submit but jQuery submit event runs anyways

Tags: jquery, html, forms, firefox, submit

I have a text field in a form that is set to `type="url"`. Before submitting Firefox seems to verify whether the URL is correct or not, if the URL is invalid it will not submit it. However, jQuery's function `$("element").submit()` is run even if the form is not submitted. How can I avoid this?

My form is as following:

```
<form id="form-add-dataset" role="form" action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
    ...
    <input type="url" name="authors_website" class="form-control" autofocus>
    ...
    <button id="upload-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Upload</button></div>
</form>
```

My jQuery code is as following:

```
$("#form-add-dataset").submit(function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can add the `novalidate` attribute to your `<form>` to prevent FireFox from validating it I believe

Answer (score 1):

you can put your event on the `<button id="upload-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"></buton>` and return the good value for submitting or not your form.

```
$('#upload-button').on('click', function(){
  if(){ // test your params
   return false; // here if you return false the form are not submit
  }
  return true; // but if you return true the form is submit
});
```